# Reporting on multiple time ranges

Tags: sql, date, time

I have a basic query (Select field from table, etc) where I can easily put in created between 1491721200 and 1492326000 and it works fine.  It's simple!  My question is, can I have one query that will give me data for multiple time ranges?  I would like to select the data from Sunday through Thursday from 2-8pm PST in this one query.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: which dbms are you using, and which data type do you use?

Comment: Give me just date if possible :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, simple `or` will do the trick

```
SELECT * from table where 
  created between 1491721200 and 1492326000
  OR created between 149999999 and 150000000
```

Comment: Ok I want to include the query because I think it gets more complicated here :)

Comment: select A.id, A.ours_ork, B.redits_earned, (B.redits_arned/(A.ours_work*8)) as ourly_ate
from
(select id, sum(if(to_time > 1492326000, 1492326000, to_time) - if(from_time> 1491721200, from_time,1491721200))/3600 as ours_ork from utor_table
where
not from_time > 1492326000 and not to_time < 1491721200
group by id) as A
left outer join
(select t_id, sum(bid) as dits_arned
from vc_table
where tutor_uid <> "null" and 
created between 1491721200 and 1492326000
group by tid) as B
on A.id = B.t_id

Comment: Ignore the field names, I modified them just to keep them private.  But that is how the current time stamps are laid out.

Comment: @TylerNelson Please move the query from the comment to your question. Remember to format it as code (use `{}` from the editor toolbar).